# Having Trouble Creating New Calculated Column Power BI

Tags: powerbi

[image]

Hi Folks,

Can someone have a look at the ERD above and advise. I am sure it is only something small.

We are trying to create a new Calculated Column that multiplies Product_Vendors[Margin] * Customer_Order_Details[QuantityOrdered] but Power BI dosent seem to want to let us do it.

We are trying to use the formula related table, but it just seems to be working from child to parent values.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add your formula to the question?

Comment: Hi, so basically we want something like TotalStockValue = Customer_Order_Details[QuantityOnHand] * Product_Vendors[Margin] I suspect the formula is right, but the 2 child tables cant see across the parent if that makes sense.

Comment: I understand, but I doubt anyone will be able to help you without know what issue you're facing with the formula. And to know that we need to see the formula. Your question is not very clear about the exact issue that you're facing without seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

TotalStockValue = Customer_Order_Details[QuantityOnHand] * RELATED(Product_Vendors[Margin])

Try just the 'related' formula, not 'relatedtable'.  Otherwise, please post the exact formula you are trying as well as the error you are getting.